# Nativescript Android build error: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, nativescript

I created a new NativeScript JavaScript project, using an existing project as a template.  The new project builds OK on iOS, but fails on Android with the error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'nativescript_google_maps'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3..
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.3./gradle-7.3..pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.3./gradle-7.3..pom
     Required by:
         project :
```

This error does NOT occur on the existing project.  I hard-coded the versions of the various plugins that aren't at the latest level, to ensure that all the plugins are the same between the two projects. Here's the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "rrr",
  "main": "app/app.js", 
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@bradmartin/nativescript-urlhandler": "^2.0.1",
    "@kefah/nativescript-google-maps": "1.0.7",
    "@master.technology/permissions": "^2.0.1",
    "@nativescript-community/ui-material-bottom-navigation": "7.0.2",
    "@nativescript/appversion": "^2.0.0",
    "@nativescript/contacts": "2.0.4",
    "@nativescript/core": "8.3.5",
    "@nativescript/email": "^2.0.5",
    "@nativescript/firebase": "^11.1.3",
    "@nativescript/geolocation": "8.0.2",
    "@nativescript/iqkeyboardmanager": "2.0.0",
    "@nativescript/theme": "^3.0.2",
    "@triniwiz/nativescript-toasty": "^4.1.3",
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "nativescript-bitmap-factory": "^1.8.1",
    "nativescript-clipboard": "^2.1.1",
    "nativescript-danem-google-maps-utils": "^1.0.18",
    "nativescript-drop-down": "6.0.1",
    "nativescript-pdf-view": "^3.0.0-1",
    "nativescript-phone": "^3.0.3",
    "nativescript-screenshot": "^0.0.2",
    "nativescript-sqlite": "^2.8.6",
    "nativescript-ui-listview": "10.0.2",
    "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "10.0.2",
    "patch-package": "^6.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nativescript/android": "8.1.1",
    "@nativescript/ios": "8.2.3",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "5.0.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "patch-package"
  }
}
```

When I run `tns build android --log trace` on the new project I see this info:

```
Got gradle versions null from runtime v8.1.1
Exec npm view @nativescript/android  dist-tags --json 
 stdout: {
  "rc": "8.2.0-rc.0",
  "latest": "8.4.0",
  "alpha": "8.4.0-alpha.8",
  "dev": "8.4.0-dev.2",
  "beta": "8.5.0-beta.0"
}
 
 stderr: 
Exec npm view @nativescript/android@8.4.0  gradle --json 
 stdout: {
  "version": "7.5",
  "android": "7.3."
}
 
 stderr: 
Got gradle versions {"gradleVersion":"7.5","gradleAndroidPluginVersion":"7.3."} from the latest runtime v8.4.0
```

These entries do not appear in the build log for the existing project; it looks like a higher version of cradle is being used on the new project.

I've seen others report similar error messages, but I've not seen working resolutions.  For example, I did add the line to buildscript.gradle, but it has no effect:

```
dependencies {
    classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4"
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3"  // <- added this line
}
```

I've done repeated `tns clean`'s, updated the Android Studio build tools, etc., but still no luck.  I welcome any insight.

Edit 1/22/2022:

Here's the `tns doctor` output:

```
✔ Getting environment information 

No issues were detected.
✔ Your ANDROID_HOME environment variable is set and points to correct directory.
✔ Your adb from the Android SDK is correctly installed.
✔ The Android SDK is installed.
✔ A compatible Android SDK for compilation is found.
✔ Javac is installed and is configured properly.
✔ The Java Development Kit (JDK) is installed and is configured properly.
✔ Xcode is installed and is configured properly.
✔ xcodeproj is installed and is configured properly.
✔ CocoaPods are installed.
✔ CocoaPods update is not required.
✔ CocoaPods are configured properly.
✔ Your current CocoaPods version is newer than 1.0.0.
✔ Python installed and configured correctly.
✔ The Python 'six' package is found.
✔ Xcode version 13.3.1 satisfies minimum required version 10.
✔ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
⚠ Update available for component nativescript. Your current version is 8.1.5 and the latest available version is 8.4.0.
⚠ Update available for component @nativescript/core. Your current version is 8.3.5 and the latest available version is 8.4.6.
⚠ Update available for component @nativescript/ios. Your current version is 8.2.3 and the latest available version is 8.4.1.
⚠ Update available for component @nativescript/android. Your current version is 8.1.1 and the latest available version is 8.4.0.
```

Is there a way to control which version of gradle is used?

Answer (score 1):

Upon advice from the NativeSript Android Discord channel, I updated the NativeScript CLI, core, and platforms to the latest versions and can build successfully.  This doesn't answer why the existing project would build and the new one wouldn't, but does bypass the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on your same exact error -- `Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3..` although I'm getting it over the @nativescript/camera plugin and unfortunately in my case I can't update anything.

I suspect that, at least in my case, whatever is writing the file `/platforms/tmpPlugin/camera/build.gradle` is where the problem is coming from.  I've noticed that the version it's trying to load is `7.3.` - (I think that second trailing dot in the error message `Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3..` is a period to indicate the end of the error's sentence)

if that is true, then the fact that there's a number missing after `7.3.` makes me suspect that it should really be `7.3.0` and if I go directly to https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.3.0/gradle-7.3.0.pom then I get an instant file download.  I think something is nixing the 0's in the version number which is why that second dot is appended to the version string (`7.3.`) but I have no idea how to correct it.  I don't see anything with a "7." even when I search every file in the entire app's codebase so I don't even know where its getting `7.3.` as a version number from.

I know it doesn't exactly solve the issue perse, but hopefully it gives someone out there a bit more insight on where to look to solve this problem.  I don't know enough about the inner-workings of nativescript to know where to look or how to fix it.

Comment: If you edit the gradle file, does it then work?  If so, you can use patch-package to maintain that change locally on your system and even submit a PR request.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work.  Something writes to that file anytime I try and compile the code so my edits just get overwritten.  I noticed the camera plugin doesn't have the include.gradle file in the root directory of the plugin so I tried adding that and setting the gradle version there but it seems the file just gets ignored :/

Comment: @Rich... first of all, Thank You so much for your post, and more specifically the trailing period. Of course, that doesn't look like a valid version string to begin with. I also ran into the same issue on my setup while I was trying `ns run android`. I have a pnpm workspace, managed via `turborepo`, and I was using the tasks to run this as one of my apps in the monorepo. In my case, the problem was that - I had `nativescript: 8.5.3` installed globally, but `~8.1.3` as a workspace dependency in my repo(not sure why I chose 8.1.3 as dependency). Aligning with global version fixed it for me.

Comment: The `turborepo` task was picking up on the workspace dependency and not the global one. Instead of choosing to build with a global install, I went ahead and aligned both version to `8.5.3` and let a build happen with a package dependency instead of a global install, and the builds went fine. I was able to see my starter app in Android virtual device. So I suppose, that helps me avoid the issue. I know this is not the real problem as to why that **malformed version string**, but at least it may help avoid issues for somebody, as it did for me.